# Yii CListView Pagination customising

Tags: php, pagination, yii

is there a way to customise the Yii CListView Pagination object to show

previous 1 of n pages next

rather then

previous 1,2,3 next ?

thanks

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager#maxButtonCount-detail)

Comment: not the answer, I need it to say current page OF max pages

Comment: Please rewrite your question in *proper* English then, because I have no idea what you are looking for.

Comment: If you understood English it would make sense, its quite a simple question. If you don't have anything of any use to add to this question why not troll somewhere else?

Comment: you'll have to extend the clinkpager, there are no options currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this by simply passing parameters to the CLinkPager in order to modify its output. So, there is no *more elegant method*.

But you can very easily override the Pager class by extending CLinkPager and just change the createPageButtons()-Method in the following way:

```
Yii::import('web.widgets.pagers.CLinkPager');
class YourLinkPager extends CLinkPager{
    /**
 * Creates the page buttons.
 * @return array a list of page buttons (in HTML code).
 */
protected function createPageButtons()
{
    if(($pageCount=$this->getPageCount())<=1)
        return array();

    list($beginPage,$endPage)=$this->getPageRange();
    $currentPage=$this->getCurrentPage(false); // currentPage is calculated in getPageRange()
    $buttons=array();

    // first page
    $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->firstPageLabel,0,self::CSS_FIRST_PAGE,$currentPage<=0,false);

    // prev page
    if(($page=$currentPage-1)<0)
        $page=0;
    $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->prevPageLabel,$page,self::CSS_PREVIOUS_PAGE,$currentPage<=0,false);

    /* 
             * !!! change has been made here !!!
             */
    $buttons[]='<li>Page '.$this->getCurrentPage(false).' of '.$this->getPageCount().'</li>';

    // next page
    if(($page=$currentPage+1)>=$pageCount-1)
        $page=$pageCount-1;
    $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->nextPageLabel,$page,self::CSS_NEXT_PAGE,$currentPage>=$pageCount-1,false);

    // last page
    $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($this->lastPageLabel,$pageCount-1,self::CSS_LAST_PAGE,$currentPage>=$pageCount-1,false);

    return $buttons;
}
}
```

Comment: +1, aside from a few mistakes(i think typos) this should work

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5776-customise-the-clinkpager/

Comment: is there a more elegant method by passing parameters to ClistView or the pager class?

Comment: this hasnt been answered, its just your original reply in the forum instead.